# How to test Camel onExceptions blocks with long redeliveryDelays in tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-camel

When testing a camel route I have a parent class with handling:

```
 onException(org.xyz.SomeException.class)
    .maximumRedeliveries(7)
    .redeliveryDelay(25000)
    .handled()
    .end();
```

And I have a child RouteBuilder class that inherits from that one, and uses `super.configure()`

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
  super.configure();

  from("direct:mytest")
      .routeId("mytest")
      .process(new SomeProcessor())
      .to("mock:endpoint");
}
```

I'd like to run this in a test, and I have a harness where I assert it redelivered 7 times... However, when the test runs I still have to wait 25s between each redelivery. Is there a way to make Camel ignore the redeliveryDelay, or somehow set it to 0 for only tests?

If i try to redefine the redeliveryDelay in the tests, it overwrites what was inherited from the parent?

Is there a way to get the parent inherited onException definition and only modify the redeliveryDelay property?

I've tried this

```
routeDefintionUnderTest.onException(org.xyzSomeException.class).getRedeliveryPolicy();
```

but it returns null, as if it can't get what was defined with the super.configure() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found i could access the redelivery programmatically like this:

```
class RouteUnderTest extends MyRoute {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    super.configure();

    final List<OnExceptionDefinition> onExceptionDefinitions = super.getRouteCollection().getOnExceptions();

    for (final OnExceptionDefinition oed : onExceptions) {
      oed.redeliveryDelay(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use
[PropertyPlaceholder-OverridingProperties](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/using-propertyplaceholder.html#UsingPropertyPlaceholder-OverridingPropertiesfromCamelTestKit) ?
Your timeout could be put into a variable in your blueprint and override on testing purpose.